# Package upgrade is failing in 22.04

Tags: package-management, updates

For the past 2 days, I've tried to update Ubuntu 22.04 using the sudo command, and I get the following error:

```
david@david-XPS-15-9530:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-compute-390 : Breaks: libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (!= 390.147-0ubuntu1) but 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-compute-390 (!= 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 390.147-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-390 : Breaks: libnvidia-decode-390:i386 (!= 390.147-0ubuntu1) but 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-decode-390 (!= 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 390.147-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-encode-390 : Breaks: libnvidia-encode-390:i386 (!= 390.147-0ubuntu1) but 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-encode-390:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-encode-390 (!= 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 390.147-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-fbc1-390 : Breaks: libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 (!= 390.147-0ubuntu1) but 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-fbc1-390 (!= 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 390.147-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-390 : Breaks: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (!= 390.147-0ubuntu1) but 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-gl-390 (!= 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 390.147-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Breaks: libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 (!= 390.147-0ubuntu1) but 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-ifr1-390 (!= 390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 390.147-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
david@david-XPS-15-9530:~$
```

Seems there are issues with nvidia-390 libraries.
I ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before that.

Can anyone assist me on this.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`? Run it and try again.

Comment: Then run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: david@david-XPS-15-9530:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install both the 32bit and 64bit libraries at once. Do you know which ones you need? If you run `lscpu` it will print some details and the first entry will be the Architecture, please add this output to your question.

Comment: david@david-XPS-15-9530:~$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               60
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  4
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            3
    CPU max MHz:         3200.0000
    CPU min MHz:

Comment: I've removed the Nvidia driver and reverted to X.org X server for display driver and that solved the update problem. Seems there is an issue with the NVIDIA 390 driver & software with latest update. Previously I had no issues.

Comment: try sudo apt install --reinstall libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386

Comment: "Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled." ... then a long message, too long for a SO comment, then an MEK boot password, which seemed like it was rejected, but upon rebooting, was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt autoremove` before update and upgrade